# Django: How do I allow views and methods with AllowAny permission to bypass authentication with HttpOnly JWT token cookies?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware, cookie-httponly

I have applied JWT authentication with HttpOnly cookies using a custom middleware. Now, the middleware checks for the presence of `access` and `refresh` tokens as HttpOnly cookies in every request. Everything works well.

But, it retuns `'KeyError': 'access'` if I request for a page that does not require authentication, say, the homepage or bloglist or blogdetail page. How do I remove this need for `access` token in these views with `permissions` set to `AllowAny` and also in some views where only the `GET` method permission is set to `AllowAny`?

My view:

```
class TagView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            self.permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
        elif self.request.method == 'GET':
            self.permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny,]
        elif self.request.method == 'POST':
            self.permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
        return super(TagView, self).get_permissions()
```

If request method is `GET`, the middleware should pass the request even if no `access` cookie is found.
Now, it checks for the `access` cookie in every request. I added a line to skip asking for tokens if the request method is `GET` and if there is no cookie in the request, to mark it as `AllowAny` view, but I think it is unsafe.

My middleware:

```
class AuthorizationHeaderMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        pass
        
    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path == '/api/auth/login/':
            return self.get_response(request)

        # for AllowAny views, I am doing this, but I think it is unsafe
        elif request.method == 'GET' and request.COOKIES == {}: # no cookies present
            return self.get_response(request)

        else:
            try:
                access_token = request.COOKIES['access']
                key = settings.SECRET_KEY
                jwt.decode(access_token, key, algorithms=["HS256"])
                request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = f'Bearer {access_token}'
                return self.get_response(request)

            except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
                refresh_cookie = request.COOKIES['refresh']
                data = {"refresh": refresh_cookie}
                resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/refresh/', data=data)
                access_token_string = json.loads(resp.text)["access"]
                request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = f'Bearer {access_token_string}'
                return self.get_response(request)
```

How do I allow selected `AllowAny` views and methods if they don't have HttpOnly JWT token cookies?